# Python, Django mod_wsgi, virtualenv errror: ImportError: No module named os (paths are not correct)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am trying to set up a Django appliaction on Apache using mod_wsgi but it I keep getting an error:

```
ImportError: No module named os
```

I am on Centos. The system version of Python is 2.6, but I have asked teh sysadmin to install 2.7. Mod_wsgi was installed from a package manager, so is probably using python 2.6.

The Apache file for wsgi.conf contains the following:

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/mysite/virtualenv_2.7/bin
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/mysite/collaboratorimport/webform:/var/www/html/mysite/virtualenv_2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

At the top of th wsgi.py script I print the sys path

```
import sys 
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

The error log contains the following messages, that show that mod_wsgi is looking for python2.6 libraries:

```
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=2148): Unable to import 'site' module.
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python26.zip
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python2.6/
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python2.6/lib-old
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] /var/www/html/uploads.cnag.cat/virtualenv_2.7/bin/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error]   File "/var/www/html/mysite/collaboratorimport/webform/webform/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error]     import os
[Tue Nov 18 16:45:31 2014] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

So it looks like mod_wsgi (or something) is appending bin/lib64/python2.6 to the paths I have given it. Is this because it is expecting me to use python2.6?

Can I use my virtualenv (python2.7) with mod_wsgi that is expecting python2.6. How can I fix the paths, so that they point to the correct place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't mix and match like this. You'll need to install a version of mod_wsgi that is compiled against Python 2.7.